# How to perform a Burn Operation in GMAT via python api

Tags: python, gmat

'm testing the python api of GMAT (2022). I'm able to instantiate a satellite object and do propagation in steps. I would like to include an instant burn operation in the simulation, but the code just exists when on the line invoking the burn operation. Does someone know how this can be done via python api of GMAT?

Thanks.

What I've tried is following (Orbiter and Forces are initialized):

```
# Apply a delta-v to the spacecraft at a specified time
# dv_time = start_date + 6 * gmat.Time('Hour')
dv_magnitude = 1.0  # Change in velocity in km/s
burn = gmat.Construct("ImpulsiveBurn", "EarthOrbiterBurn")
burn.SetField("CoordinateSystem", "EarthMJ2000Eq")
burn.SetField("Element1", dv_magnitude)
burn.SetField("Element2", dv_magnitude)
burn.SetField("Element3", dv_magnitude)
burn.SetSpacecraftToManeuver(earthorb)

burn_maneuver = gmat.Construct("Maneuver", "BurnManeuver")
burn_maneuver.SetField("Burn", "DeltaV")
burn_maneuver.SetField("Spacecraft", "EarthOrbiter")
# burn_maneuver.Help()

# Perform top level initialization
gmat.Initialize()

# Setup the spacecraft that is propagated
pdprop.AddPropObject(earthorb)
pdprop.PrepareInternals()

# Refresh the 'gator reference
gator = pdprop.GetPropagator()gmat.BeginMissionSequence().Execute()
    
    for i in range(0, 1000):
        # Take a 60 second step, showing the state before and after propagation
    
        if 25 == i:  # < 50:
            # Apply the delta-v to the spacecraft
            burn_maneuver.Execute()
    
        gator.Step(60)
```

Again, I'm not really getting any error, the process simply exists:

```
Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)
```

Comment: That exit code is [an indication that something is going wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50620954/process-finished-with-exit-code-1073741819-0xc0000005-pycharm)